# In PHP how would I push the values of an array on to the end of itself

Tags: php, arrays, push

Say I have an array:

```
$myArray = array("foo", "bar");
```

What is a good way to repeat the values in the array onto the end of the array so that:

```
$myArray = array("foo", "bar", "foo", "bar");
```

I thought maybe array_push would work like this:

```
array_push($myArray, $myArray);
```

but that actually pushes the array object and not the values of the array.

Comment: http://hexmen.com/blog/2008/11/concatenating-arrays-in-php/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can do this with `array_merge`

```
$tmp = $myArray;

$myArray = array_merge($myArray, $tmp);
```

This will rely on you not worry about the array keys..

Another solution would be:

```
$tmp = $myArray;
foreach($tmp as $val) {
    $myArray[] = $val;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

How about `$myArray = array_merge($myArray, $myArray);`?

Answer (score 1):

If you explicitly want to duplicate the *values* of an array even if it is associative:

```
$myArray = array("foo" => "apple", "bar" => "orange");

$myArray = array_merge($tmp = array_values($myArray), $tmp);
```

The new array will contain `("apple", "orange", "apple", "orange")` - note: it is now indexed.